# Tweet from website

Tags: twitter

How can you tweet from a website to twitter. I need to build a comment box that posts questions to twitter?

Thanks,
c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [Twitter Developer Center](http://dev.twitter.com/) and the [Twitter API wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage) would be a good place to start.

There are libraries for plenty of programming languages already that will make development easier. Find them in the wiki.

Comment: Goign through it now. Thought there might already be some code written as I'm in a rush. Ta!

Comment: There's plenty of code already written.  If you don't mention what programming language you're using in your question, how do you expect anyone to help you find that code?

Comment: Sorry Wooble. Got a grasp of it now. Using @anywhere for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use their API http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage